# WooCommerce products shortcode order by ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom template that is displaying a specific category of products:

[products category="Watches" per_page="18" paginate="true" orderby=""]

My 'Watches' all have an ACF field which holds a rank number which determines the order in which they should be displayed. How can I add this into the orderby options? The ACF field name is 'rank'.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

I have tried adding various ordering options into the product's normal meta but this doesn't give me enough functionality.

Comment: You can't do that via the ordering parameters the shortcode offers by default. You will need to hook into the query argument parser, and modify the resulting query to use your desired ordering criteria, using the `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` filter.

Comment: Thank you - that sounds exactly what i'm after. I'm relatively unfamiliar with how to do this - how would I add the rank meta key into the query argument parser?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters shows how to order by a meta key.

Comment: I have this:
add_filter('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'woocommerce_rlx_orderby');
function woocommerce_rlx_orderby() {
 
  $args = array(
  'meta_key' => 'rank',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
}

But it doesn't seem to be working - where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're not supposed to _make_ a query yourself at this point. You need to manipulate the values passed in via the `$query_args` parameter, and then _return_ that parameter at the end of your callback function.

Comment: Thank you - apologies, i'm very much trying to learn this right now. Do you have an example please? It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The principle of how this filter works and what the callback function needs to return, you can find in several places, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53874668/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51830954/1427878